# What is retracting in the context of OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have scribbled the term "retracting in OCaml" in a small space in my notebook and now I can't seem to recollect what it was about nor can I find anything about it on the internet.

Does this term really exist or is it my lecturer's own notation for some property of OCaml. My classmates also don't seem to remember what it was about so I just want to confirm if I was dreaming or not.

Comment: Well, there appears to be something called "retract" in type theory, which appears to refer to defining equivalence classes of values to get a coarser-grained type. If your class is on the theoretical side, maybe this is it? I personally never heard the term used in the OCaml context. I am no type theorist, you understand.

Comment: We were studying about lexical analyses and parsing and yes we were discussing about equivalence classes for tokens. Is retracting about this itself?

Comment: You can google up something called a "retract" in group theory that sounds something like an equivalence class construct (where the set of equivalence classes is a subgroup). Would anybody use this to describe classes of tokens? It seem like a stretch. I can't say much more, I'm out of my depth already :-)

Comment: never heard of the word in ocaml parsing personally

Comment: If I were you I would ask the lecturer. (If you were me, on the other hand, you would probably have written down the wrong word or written it so badly it could say anything.)

Comment: Just love to see a *retraction* question asked by *Banach* on SO :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible explanation: in math, a *retraction* is a left inverse of a morphism (see this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28category_theory%29)). In particular, a parser can be seen as a retraction w.r.t. a given pretty-printer: start from an abstract syntax tree (AST) and pretty-print it, then parsing the resulting source code should yield the original AST (while the opposite is not necessarily true). It doesn't have much to do with OCaml *per se* but it is linked to an algebraic view (of compiling) which is quite common in functional programming.